# How do I understand that caching is used in Spark?

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, mesos

In my **Scala/Spark** application, I create **DataFrame**. I plan to use this Dataframe several times throughout the program. For that's why I decided to used `.cache()` method for that DataFrame. As you can see inside the loop I filter DataFrame several times with different values. For some reason `.count()` method returns me the always the same result. In fact, it must return two different count values. Also, I notice strange behavior in **Mesos**. It feels like the `.cache()` method is not being executed. After creating the DataFrame, the program goes to this part of code `if (!df.head(1).isEmpty)` and performs it for a very long time. I assumed that the caching process would run for a long time, and the other processes would use this cache and run quickly. What do you think is the problem?

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame

var df: DataFrame = spark
    .read
    .option("delimiter", "|")
    .csv("/path_to_the_files/")
    .filter(col("col5").isin("XXX", "YYY", "ZZZ"))

df.cache()

var array1 = Array("111", "222")

var array2 = Array("333")

var storage = Array(array1, array2)

if (!df.head(1).isEmpty) {
    for (item <- storage) {
        df.filter(
            col("col1").isin(item:_*)
        )

        println("count: " + df.count())
    }
}
```

Comment: Check https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html#rdd-persistence: _"You can **mark** an RDD to be persisted using the persist() or cache() methods on it. **The first time it is computed in an action, it will be kept in memory on the nodes.** "_

Comment: One change that could definitely speed up the job is the replacement of `isin` with `left join` since you are counting how many times an item of storage is present on col1. Although I am not sure if that is an option for your case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In fact, it must return two different count values.

Why? You are calling it on the same `df`. Maybe you meant something like

```
val df1 = df.filter(...)
println("count: " + df1.count())
```

> I assumed that the caching process would run for a long time, and the other processes would use this cache and run quickly.

It does, but only when the first [action](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html#rdd-operations) which depends on this dataframe is executed, and `head` is that action. So you should expect exactly

> the program goes to this part of code `if (!df.head(1).isEmpty)` and performs it for a very long time

Without caching, you'd also get the same time for both `df.count()` calls, unless Spark detects it and enables caching on its own.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. In my case, I have one huge DataFrame which in this example called `df`. I am trying to filter this Dataframe with different values inside the loop. As far as I understand, in each iteration of the loop, I have to create a new DataFrame and check its count, right? What sequence of my code would speed up its work in your opinion? Do you think it makes sense to use `.persist()` with a certain level instead of `.cache()` to speed things up?

Comment: "unless Spark detects it and enables caching on its own." -> interesting, can you explicit this point ?

Comment: @EnzoBnl I don't actually know if it ever does, this was a caveat just in case.